# std::pair as key in map

Tags: c++, search, intervals, stdmap

I have a large dataset of images, taken at specific times where each image capture `start_time` and `stop_time` are known and encoded as doubles. 
I want to load each consecutive image into my simulation based on the simulation time, ie - check when the current simulation time falls within the start/stop interval.

I want to use a map for this, where the key is a `std::pair<double, double>` of start & stop time and the value is the full path to the image.

```
std::map<std::pair<double, double>, std::string> _sequence; // t1, t2 and full path
```

**My question:**
How can I search such a map to find if _currentTime is within an interval pair?

Comment: `std::map<...>` is not a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)...

Comment: You probably will need write a custom Comparer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132092%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Have a look at [`boost interval container library`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html). From the docs: An [`interval_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost/icl/interval_base_map.html) is a map that is implemented as a map of interval value pairs

Comment: @SteveLorimer - thank you, I will most definitely

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use a `map` keyed on `std::pair<double, double>` if searching for inclusion is the main thing you want to do. That's just not an operation that makes sense with that data structure.

But if you insist, the code would look something like this (in C++11):

```
bool isWithinInterval() const {
    for (const auto& pr : _sequence) {
        if (_currentTime >= pr.first.first && _currentTime <= pr.first.second) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Pre-C++11, same idea, just slightly different loop syntax. Ideally, we'd use `std::find_if`, but it's a hassle to express the map's `value_type`. In C++14 though, no such hassle:

```
auto it = std::find_if(_sequence.begin(),
                       _sequence.end(),
                       [_currentTime](const auto& pr) {
                           return _currentTime >= pr.first.first && _currentTime <= pr.first.second;
                       });
return it != _sequence.end();
```

Or just:

```
return std::any_of(_sequence.begin(), _sequence.end(),
                   [_currentTime](const auto& pr) {
                       return _currentTime >= pr.first.first && _currentTime <= pr.first.second;
                   });
```

Comment: I am actually looping back and forth on which datastructure I should use. Do you have any suggestions on what would be optimal and rather quick to implement? Id really like to use something from STL. (ie not write my own binary tree class)

Comment: @mike I don't think there's anything in the standard library for intervals. It's really just sequenced containers and associative containers.

Comment: I want to learn so- why is it bad in this instance to use map? Im open to any kind of solution to this problem its just that Im more or less a rookie and map seemed like a fairly easy approach...

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be *not* to use a `std::map<std::pair<double, double>, std::string>` but rather a `std::map<double, std::pair<double, std::string>>`: you'd use `m.lower_bound(current_time)` to find the start of a range of elements where `current_time` could fit. You'd then walk the iterator until it reaches the end, falls into the relevant range, or is beyond the end time:

```
auto it = _sequence.lower_bound(current_time);
for (; it != _sequence.end() && current_time <= it->second; ++it) {
   if (it.first <= current_time) {
       // found a matching element at it
   }
}
```

Using the layout with a `std::pair<double, double>` a key has the awkward need to come up with a second time. You could use `std::make_pair(current_time, current_time)`, though.

Comment: In your example do you mean that the key is the start_time and the first in pair is the end_time?

Comment: Im asking as I probably will need to store the stop/end time at some point as well, because I think there will come a need to actually simulate the time it took to take the image (fade it in or something similar)

Comment: Yes, the key is start time, all other data is stored in the record. If that doesn't quite fit your needs, you might want to have a look at range tree which are specifically intended to deal with intervals.

Answer (score 0):

```
double search = 0.; /* or some other value */
bool found = false;
for ( auto & key_value_pair : _sequence ) {
    // key_value_pair.first == map key
    // key_value_pair.second == key's associated value
    if ( key_value_pair.first.first <= search || search <= key_value_pair.first.second ) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ( found ) {
    /* it's within an interval pair! */
} else {
    /* it's not within an interval pair! */
}
```

I would recommend also looking into [`boost::icl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, don't use std::pair as the key.  It doesn't really make sense as a key because you end up with a situation where two overlapping ranges map to the same element.

Anyhow, here is how I would implement the solution to such a problem.  `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` are your friend here.  Also, you can avoid the reverse iterator tricks by keying the values on stop time.

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ImageStuff
{
  double startTime;
  double stopTime;
  char data[1000];
};

typedef std::map<double, ImageStuff> starttime_map_type; 
starttime_map_type starttime_map;

ImageStuff & MakeImage (double start, double stop) {
  ImageStuff newImage;
  newImage.startTime = start;
  newImage.stopTime = stop;
  return starttime_map[start] = newImage;
}

starttime_map_type::iterator FindByTime (double time) {
  starttime_map_type::reverse_iterator i = starttime_map_type::reverse_iterator(starttime_map.upper_bound(time));
  if (i == starttime_map.rend() || time > i->second.stopTime) {
    printf ("Didn't find an image for time %f\n", time);
    return starttime_map.end();
  }
  else {
    printf ("Found an image for time %f\n", time);
    return i.base();
  }
  return starttime_map.end();
}


int main (void)
{
  MakeImage (4.5, 6.5);
  MakeImage (8.0, 12);
  MakeImage (1, 1.2);

  auto i = FindByTime(3);
  i = FindByTime(4.5);
  i = FindByTime(9);
  i = FindByTime(15);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question for you: I am trying to implement this but it crashes on `return starttime_map[start] = newImage;`  - do I need to initialize or do something else with starttime_map before using the MakeImage function? (otherwise its line-by-line what you wrote there)

Comment: Try breaking it up into `ImageStuff & result = starttime_map[start]; result = newImage; return result;`